# Modify VBA code to remove all duplicates apart from first 2 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have found the following code which does a good job for me at extracting the data I need but I now need to modify it. Currently it removes all duplicate rows based on active column and keeps the first row.

I need to run it on a different column and remove all duplicates apart from the first 2 rows this time.

I don't know how to change it.

Many thanks

```
Public Sub DeleteDuplicateRows()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' DeleteDuplicateRows
' This will delete duplicate records, based on the Active Column. That is,
' if the same value is found more than once in the Active Column, all but
' the first (lowest row number) will be deleted.
'
' To run the macro, select the entire column you wish to scan for
' duplicates, and run this procedure.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim R As Long
Dim N As Long
Dim V As Variant
Dim Rng As Range

On Error GoTo EndMacro
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Set Rng = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, _
                    ActiveSheet.Columns(ActiveCell.Column))

Application.StatusBar = "Processing Row: " & Format(Rng.Row, "#,##0")

N = 0
For R = Rng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
If R Mod 500 = 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing Row: " & Format(R, "#,##0")
End If

V = Rng.Cells(R, 1).Value
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Note that COUNTIF works oddly with a Variant that is equal to vbNullString.
' Rather than pass in the variant, you need to pass in vbNullString explicitly.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If V = vbNullString Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng.Columns(1), vbNullString) > 1 Then
        Rng.Rows(R).EntireRow.Delete
        N = N + 1
    End If
Else
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng.Columns(1), V) > 1 Then
        Rng.Rows(R).EntireRow.Delete
        N = N + 1
    End If
End If
Next R

EndMacro:

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox "Duplicate Rows Deleted: " & CStr(N)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the first 2 rows change the For Loop from

```
For R = Rng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
```

to:

```
For R = Rng.Rows.Count To 3 Step -1
```

To work on a different column to ActiveColumn change this line

```
Set Rng = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, _
                    ActiveSheet.Columns(ActiveCell.Column))
```

To something like:

```
    Set Rng = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, _
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn))
```

(Where column A is the column to be used)